# Source Generator cannot access project reference dependencies of target project

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

My solution has the following shape:

```
Consumer/
  Program.cs
  MessageHandler.cs
  ...
SourceGenerator/
  RabbitMQGenerator.cs
Domain/
  Messages/
    TestCommand.cs
    TestEvent.cs
```

The `Consumer` project has a project reference dependency to `Domain` and it depends on the `SourceGenerator` either via Nuget or project reference.

I am trying to build a source generator (using `IIncrementalGenerator`) to register methods to consume RabbitMQ messages. The generator does the following:

1. Looks for all message handlers (tagged with a specific attribute)
2. Looks for all messages (tagged with a specific attribute)
3. For each method in each message handler class, it look for the appropriate message type (because the message type defines the RabbitMQ queue) and register it for consumption.

If the `Messages/` folder is in the `Consumer` project, the source generator detects everything and works great. But if the messages are in the `Domain` project, the source generator cannot access them and it fails.

I also tried adding the source generator as a dependency to the `Domain` project, but that just resulted in the source generator running twice, once in each project, and not generating the desired outcome.

Basically, my generator takes part of the data needed from one project (or assembly), and the rest from another project. Is this behavior supported? If so, how can I accomplish it?

Here are my project files:
Consumer:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Other nuget dependencies -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Domain\Domain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SourceGenerator\SourceGenerator.csproj" 
                      ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" 
                      OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

Domain:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Other nuget dependencies -->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Source Generator:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
        <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>Generated</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
        <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
        <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.6.0" />

      <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Example of `MessageHandler.cs`:

```cs
[EntityHandler]
public class MessageConsumer
{
    [MessageHandler(typeof(TestCommand))]
    public Task OnTestCommand(TestCommand command)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Example of `TestCommand.cs`:

```cs
[MessageType("RabbitMQ.TestCommand")]
public class TestCommand : IRabbitMqCommand 
{
    // ...
}
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732040/how-to-access-project-referenced-assemblies-in-source-generator) that solves this issue for generators implementing the `ISourceGenerator` interface, but I cannot find anything for `IIncrementalGenerator`.

Comment: The dependency doesn't exist as source in the consumer project.

Comment: That's my bad, while simplifying the code for this post I mistyped     `<ProjectReference Include="..\Domain\Contracts.csproj" />` instad of `<ProjectReference Include="..\Domain\Domain.csproj" />` . Even with this dependency correct, my incremental generator cannot access referenced assemblies.

Comment: A project reference is compiled and the .dll is copied into the consumer. There is no source for the incremental generator to access.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense, it just isn’t supported use case of the incremental source generator.